# Xming cannot locate SSH.exe through Windows Explorer

Tags: windows, windows-subsystem-for-linux, openssh, xming

I hope this is the correct place to ask this, as it is somewhat of a Windows issue. My problem: When trying to "forward" (I think) X11 using Xming when I have an OpenGL program sitting on WSL I want to run, I can't find my SSH.exe!

Except, I can.

Image of `ssh.exe` being visible when searching outside of the Xming `ssh.exe` selection explorer:

[image: Image of ssh.exe being visible when searching outside of the Xming ssh.exe selection explorer]

Also, `where` doesn't work?

```
PS C:\Windows\System32\OpenSSH> where .\ssh.exe
PS C:\Windows\System32\OpenSSH>
```

I was *in the directory in which the .exe is,* and `where` somehow can't find it. Xming itself cannot find it, as when I open `C:\Windows\System32\`, the OpenSSH directory apparently doesn't exist! See screenshot.

Image of OpenSSH directory being unavailable when trying to go through the Xming XLaunch program:

[image: Image of OpenSSH directory being unavailable when trying to go through the Xming XLaunch program]

I've never seen this kind of thing happen before, so I don't know exactly what settings might be relevant here.

I've tried a few other things, as well:

- Tried marking `\OpenSSH\` as non-read only, but was prevented from doing so even with admin access. Perhaps this is wise.
- PuTTy connection, which results in an error for a different question. Something like "expected key exchange from server".
- Copying SSH .exe to several different locations, which did not work as Xming still couldn't find any of my attempts.

I've tried vcXsrv, but I can't get that to work either. I'm open to suggestions, my ultimate goal is to try to run an OpenGL program that I have on my WSL. I presume since WSL doesn't have its own window system, we have to pipe to Windows somehow? Not fully understanding that process. Do let me know if there is a simpler way, or some way to solve the issue I have described.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `ssh.exe` is located under `C:\Windows\System32`, what is a magic folder. It's different for 32-bit and 64-bit processes. For 64-bit processes its mapped to (invisible) `C:\Windows\Sysnative`, while for 32-bit processes it is mapped to `C:\Windows\SysWOW64` (it's probably not exactly like this, but it's enough to give you the idea). Most binaries exist in both, in their 32-bit and 64- variants.

But the `OpenSSH` exists in 64-bit variant only (`C:\Windows\Sysnative\OpenSSH`). So 32-bit processes cannot locate it via `PATH`, which contains `C:\Windows\System32\OpenSSH`, which for them maps to a non-existing `C:\Windows\SysWOW64\OpenSSH`.

I assume that your Xming is 32-bit, as well as your PowerShell instance.

You can use a full path instead:

```
C:\Windows\Sysnative\OpenSSH\ssh.exe
```

Comment: Thank you! I was able to find the .exe using the Sysnative path. Still crashed, but I can probably figure out why. Thank you so much for your help. I think this sufficiently answers the question!

Answer (score 0):

The explanation of why your `where` command didn't work: `where` in PowerShell is an alias to the `Where-Object` function, which finds powershell objects, **not** files. If you want to search for files, use `where.exe` instead!

*(I would've written this as a comment, but I don't have enough reputation.)*